# Python does not update SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to update SQL Server table through Python. But unfortunately it does not update.

I get message successful but no data was updated.

If I call the same SQL script from within SQL Server, it updates correctly.

Let me show you my script: this is my Python code:

```
PredString = '99'

conn = pymssql.connect(server="MyServer", database="MyDB", port="1433", user="****", password="******")
dfUpdate = pd.read_sql("EXEC UpdatePredictions '" + PredString + "'", conn)
conn.close()

print(dfUpdate)
```

This is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
alter procedure UpdatePredictions 
    (@PredString varchar(max)) 
as
begin
    update MyTable 
    set PredMths = @PredString 

    select 'Updated.'
end
```

When I run Python code I get "Updated" but actually no record was updated

But when I call from SQL Server:

```
 EXEC UpdatePredictions '99'
```

I get message "Updated" and records are actually updated

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get Python to update the table?

Comment: Do you do a `COMMIT` somewhere?

Comment: `# you must call commit() to persist your data if you don't set autocommit to True
conn.commit()`

Comment: no, it is Stored procedure in SQL it commits after finishing the SP automatically

Comment: @LinPy to commit in SQL side or in Python?

Comment: in Python see : http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html

Comment: Before closing connection call conn.commit(), In python script.

Comment: Thanks, that did it :) .. plz put it as an answer so I mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the guys who commented the answer.

As no one have made it as an answer, I will so I can mark it, so other people can find the answer easily in the future.

the problem was that Python connection wasn't committing update statement.

therefore I have to add this line after sending the update

```
conn.commit()
```